# Issue while sending data via Bluetooth

Tags: c#

I use the following code for server to send/receive some strings via bluetooth between to/from client, and to send some files to client only:

```
  try
  {
    //////////WELCOME DATA MESSAGE TO BE SENT (START)///////////////
    byte[] sync_welcome_sent = new byte[2] { 0x55, 0xAA };
    byte[] message_type_welcome_sent = new byte[1] { 0x00 }; //will need if statement
    byte[] number_of_slides_welcome_sent = BitConverter.GetBytes((System.Int16)Directory.GetFiles(image_path).Length); //count number of pictures in local folder
    byte[] recording_state_welcome_sent = new byte[1] { 0x00 }; //will need if statement

    byte[] welcome_data_message_sent = new byte[sync_welcome_sent.Length + message_type_welcome_sent.Length + number_of_slides_welcome_sent.Length + recording_state_welcome_sent.Length];

    //copy all byte array into one big packet to be sent
    sync_welcome_sent.CopyTo(welcome_data_message_sent, 0);
    message_type_welcome_sent.CopyTo(welcome_data_message_sent, sync_welcome_sent.Length);
    number_of_slides_welcome_sent.CopyTo(welcome_data_message_sent, sync_welcome_sent.Length + message_type_welcome_sent.Length);
    recording_state_welcome_sent.CopyTo(welcome_data_message_sent, sync_welcome_sent.Length + message_type_welcome_sent.Length + number_of_slides_welcome_sent.Length);

    //send the packet
    mStream.Write(welcome_data_message_sent, 0, welcome_data_message_sent.Length);

    //clear the stream for next packet
    mStream.Flush();

   //display the message to the user
   updateUI("Sent: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(welcome_data_message_sent));
  ////////////WELCOME DATA MESSAGE TO BE SENT (END)///////////////

  ///////////WELCOME DATA MESSAGE TO BE RECEIVED (START)//////////
  byte[] welcome_data_message_received = new byte[5];
  mStream.Read(welcome_data_message_received, 0, welcome_data_message_received.Length);

  //clear the stream for next packet
  mStream.Flush();

  //instantiate arrays for received data
  byte[] sync_welcome_received = new byte[2];
  byte[] message_type_welcome_received = new byte[1];
  byte[] slideID_welcome_received = new byte[2];

  //copy bytes from received packet to separate arrays
  Array.Copy(welcome_data_message_received, 0, sync_welcome_received, 0, 2);
  Array.Copy(welcome_data_message_received, 2, message_type_welcome_received, 0, 1);
  Array.Copy(welcome_data_message_received, 3, slideID_welcome_received, 0, 2);

  //reverse all byte arrays
  if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
  {
     Array.Reverse(sync_welcome_received);
     Array.Reverse(message_type_welcome_received);Array.Reverse(slideID_welcome_received);
  }

  //retrieve the received data into original format
  int message_type_welcome_received_final = (int)message_type_welcome_received[0]; //then convert all sbyte array's bytes to int
  int slideID_begin_from = BitConverter.ToInt16(slideID_welcome_received, 0); //then convert all sbyte array's bytes to int

  updateUI("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(welcome_data_message_received));
  /////////////WELCOME DATA MESSAGE TO BE RECEIVED (END)///////////////

  for (int i = slideID_begin_from; i <= count; i++)
  {
     //////////////SLIDE DATA MESSAGE TO BE SENT (START)//////////////
     byte[] sync_data_sent = new byte[2] { 0x55, 0xAA };
     byte[] message_type_data_sent = new byte[1] { 0x01 }; //will need if statement
     byte[] slide_id_data_sent = BitConverter.GetBytes((System.Int16)i); //slideID that is being sent to the client
     byte[] image_only_data_sent = new byte[1] { 0x00 }; //will need if statement

     byte[] image_data_data_sent = File.ReadAllBytes(picture_paths[i]);
     byte[] image_data_length_data_sent = BitConverter.GetBytes(image_data_data_sent.Length);

     byte[] text_data_data_sent;
     byte[] text_data_length_data_sent;

     if (!is_image_only)
     {
        text_data_data_sent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(slide_notes[i]);
        text_data_length_data_sent = BitConverter.GetBytes(text_data_data_sent.Length);
     }
     else
     {
        text_data_data_sent = new byte[0];
        text_data_length_data_sent = new byte[0];
     }    

     byte[] slide_data_message_sent = new byte[sync_data_sent.Length + message_type_data_sent.Length + slide_id_data_sent.Length + image_only_data_sent.Length + image_data_data_sent.Length + text_data_data_sent.Length + image_data_length_data_sent.Length + text_data_length_data_sent.Length];

     //copy all byte array into one big packet to be sent
     sync_data_sent.CopyTo(slide_data_message_sent, 0);
     message_type_data_sent.CopyTo(slide_data_message_sent, sync_data_sent.Length);
     slide_id_data_sent.CopyTo(slide_data_message_sent, sync_data_sent.Length + message_type_data_sent.Length);
     image_only_data_sent.CopyTo(slide_data_message_sent, sync_data_sent.Length + message_type_data_sent.Length + slide_id_data_sent.Length);
     image_data_data_sent.CopyTo(slide_data_message_sent, sync_data_sent.Length + message_type_data_sent.Length + slide_id_data_sent.Length + image_only_data_sent.Length);
     text_data_data_sent.CopyTo(slide_data_message_sent, sync_data_sent.Length + message_type_data_sent.Length + slide_id_data_sent.Length + image_only_data_sent.Length + image_data_data_sent.Length);
     image_data_length_data_sent.CopyTo(slide_data_message_sent, sync_data_sent.Length + message_type_data_sent.Length + slide_id_data_sent.Length + image_only_data_sent.Length + image_data_data_sent.Length + text_data_data_sent.Length);
     text_data_length_data_sent.CopyTo(slide_data_message_sent, sync_data_sent.Length + message_type_data_sent.Length + slide_id_data_sent.Length + image_only_data_sent.Length + image_data_data_sent.Length + text_data_data_sent.Length + image_data_length_data_sent.Length);


     //send the packet
     mStream.Write(slide_data_message_sent, 0, slide_data_message_sent.Length);

     //clear the stream for next packet
     mStream.Flush();

     //display the message to the user
     updateUI("Sent: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(slide_data_message_sent));
     /////////SLIDE DATA MESSAGE TO BE SENT (END)/////////////////

     /////////SLIDE DATA MESSAGE TO BE RECEIVED (START)///////////
     byte[] slide_data_message_received = new byte[5];
     mStream.Read(slide_data_message_received, 0, slide_data_message_received.Length);

     //clear the stream for next packet
     mStream.Flush();

     //instantiate arrays for received data
     byte[] sync_slide_received = new byte[2];
     byte[] message_type_slide_received = new byte[1];
     byte[] slideID_slide_received = new byte[2];

     //copy bytes from preceived packet to separate arrays
     Array.Copy(slide_data_message_received, 0, sync_slide_received, 0, 2);
     Array.Copy(slide_data_message_received, 2, message_type_slide_received, 0, 1);
     Array.Copy(slide_data_message_received, 3, slideID_slide_received, 0, 2);

     //retrieve the received data into original format
     int message_type_slide_received_final = (int)message_type_slide_received[0]; //then convert all sbyte array's bytes to int
     int slideID_data_received = BitConverter.ToInt16(slideID_slide_received, 0); //then convert all sbyte array's bytes to int

     updateUI("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(slide_data_message_received));
     ///////////SLIDE DATA MESSAGE TO BE RECEIVED (END)////////////
   }                
}
catch (IOException exception)
{
   updateUI("Client has disconnected");
 }
}
```

The problem occurs here:

```
mStream.Write(slide_data_message_sent, 0, slide_data_message_sent.Length);
```

As soon as I send this packet, it catches the exception and client disconnects. So the problem occurs when putting data in writing stream second time. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: In your exception handler, you should add logging of exception details. Currently neither your client, nor you and nor us can understand what exception you are seeing. This is not only essential for answering this question (please post the exception here), but also for you, when supporting this part of code if it fails at your client. So besides adding exception details to your question above, I strongly recommend you logging full exception details somewhere instead of throwing them away.

Comment: Why are you using the same stream for both reads and writes?